# Remove or escape double quotes

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm trying to store items in localStorage; here is my function:

```
function AddToCart(varer) {

    var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
    users.push(varer);
    console.log(varer);

    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
}
```

And result will be in under Application Tab :

[image]

And then I'm trying Looping through localStorage and send data to controller:

```
    var holderHTML = '';
    var params = "";
    var seperator = "";
    var info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));

        for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
            var Val = info[i];
            var key = JSON.stringify(Val)

            params += seperator + "items=" + key;
            seperator = "&";               
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/serializeItemsLine",
            data: params,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (values) {

                console.log(values);

            }

         })
```

But the data I'm trying to send contains double quotes (decoded %22) and because of that my action couldn't retrieve data:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:xxxx/User/serializeItemsLine?items=%22ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47%22&items=%223e58aa74-4585-4bee-b2e0-ed39a1d95442%22
```

Query string parameters :

```
items: "ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47"
items: "3e58aa74-4585-4bee-b2e0-ed39a1d95442"
```

Decoded results:

```
items: %22ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47%22
items: %223e58aa74-4585-4bee-b2e0-ed39a1d95442%22
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public string serializeItemsLine(Guid[] items) {

}
```

Comment: If there is more than one query parameter with the same name, some of them may be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it this way: `+ "items=" + Val`.

There is no need here to call `JSON.stringify()`. Your API isn't expecting JSON, so you shouldn't feed it JSON.